# How to git clone --bare only one branch and update easily

Tags: git, clone, diskspace, bare

I have a big web app project with hundreds of commits and multiple branches.

I want to have a test-server with **very limited** space that only needs to be able to download the last content of one branch to READ.

Is `git clone --bare <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch` the solution to my needs?

The problem I see here is that I cannot update easy the content as `git pull` will not work.

Comment: That seems about right, I would also check into `git clone --depth 1 <url> --branch <branch>`

Comment: If your server does not need to perform source control, why not deploy the files directly *to* your server from some system that has more space, using some sort of deployment software? (This might be as simple as using rsync, though you could get much fancier.) Then you don't even need to install Git itself on the server.